# How to have a standard "base" repo (but not a shared library repo) and have derivative project repos?

Tags: git

I have a main repo (repo 1) that I work with. I have another repo (repo 2) that needs to fit into the first one and I'm not sure how I could have them both in the same folder. The idea is that I have a standard codebase that I need in each project - yet each project is it's own git repo.

```
/project
    /.git(repo 2)
    /.git(repo 1)
    /repo_2_sub
        /repo_2_sub_sub
            /repo_1_sub_sub
    /repo_1_sub
        /repo_1_sub_sub
        /repo_2_sub_sub
```

None of the files overlap - but some of the folder structures do. So sometimes certain folders from one repo will be in the other repo.

How can I work so these two repositories build the complete codebase?

**UPDATE**

Both git repos exist in the same root project folder level. They cannot be submodules since they cross back and forth through each other as shown above. They are not separate folders.

**UPDATE 2**

Wait, maybe this is easier than I thought. Can you clone a standard codebase repo and then create a new branch that is your project and then just keep merging that branch with the codebase repo each time it changes?

Comment: Reading through the updates and answers here, it sounds like the right answer is to separate the two distinct projects into a saner dependency structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wait, maybe this is easier than I
>   thought. Can you clone a standard
>   codebase repo and then create a new
>   branch that is your project and then
>   just keep merging that branch with the
>   codebase repo each time it changes?

You could do that. I have also a project where I'm doing it like this. Most of the code is the same for all subprojects. I create a new branch for every project to keep the files that only belong to that project separated. I regularly merge the `master` branch into the other branches.

You could also create clones of the main repository. Then you would just merge the changes from the `origin/master` branch into the `master` branch in each of your projects.

Comment: It sounds like this is the easiest way to handle something like this since you don't have to explain a complex setup to each team member and for each project. Plus it seems less pron to error.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git submodule`

Update:

The standard code base that needs to be a part of all the repos has to be a seperate distinct git repository.

```
git submodule add <repo_nick_name> <repo_path>
```

will add that repo to this one. On cloning and pushing, only the `.gitmodules` file and the hash at the repo will be pushed/cloned.

```
git submodule init
```

and

```
git submodule update
```

respectively initializes and updates the remote submodule repos.

For detailed info, check the [git community book documentation on git submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) and/or scot chacon's screencast on the same.

Comment: The problem is that they are projects in the same base directory.

Comment: That shouldn't be any problem. submodules exist in the same folder as the module.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: In order to have two .git directories, when you init them, there would be some extra work. When you init, do:

```
git --git-dir=.git1 --work-tree=. init
git --git-dir=.git2 --work-tree=. init
```

Now you have two git dirs in the same directory. Not very pretty. At this point, make sure that you have .git1 and .git2 in both .gitignores, since they aren't ignored by default. Additionally, every git command you run must also have the --git-dir argument to specify which repository you're interacting with. You could setup aliases for that.

Since they're in the same base directory and submodules won't work, you could put '.gitignore' files inside both '.git/info/exclude' directories. Putting them in .git/info/exclude makes sure that the other repo doesn't pick up the exclusions.

It may take some maintenance if the two repos differ by a finer granularity than folders, but if you specify in each .gitignore the files that belong only to the OTHER repo, it should work.

See: [gitignore](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)

Comment: You can't actually have two `.git` folders - I just put them there to show what I *think I want*.

Comment: Crazy man. I don't think I'll go this route since it seems like such a hack. Plus, it would be a pain to setup a bunch of team installs like this. Awesome to know it works though!