# How to keep Drupal up to date with the GitHub repo?

Tags: git, drupal, github, dvcs

Drupal has a GitHub repository at http://github.com/drupal/drupal

I, being a newbie to Git and the DVCS world in general, and having trouble figuring out how to use this repo as a method for keeping my Drupal core up to date, so I have the following questions:

- Is this the best way to check out a specific tag from the repo?

  ```
  git clone git://github.com/drupal/drupal.git`
  git checkout DRUPAL-6-15
  ```
- How about updating to the next release when it becomes available? Just `git checkout DRUPAL-6-16`?
- How can I choose to save my own changes (such as modifications to .htaccess) rather than revert back whenever I update?
- What's the best way to add my modules and themes into my local git repo, and still retain the ability to update core whenever there's a new core release? Do I need to create a branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the best way to check out a specific tag from the repo?

Yes. It *is* the right way.

> How about updating to the next release when it becomes available? Just git checkout DRUPAL-6-16?

```
git checkout master
git pull
git tag # Lists all tags, contains releases
git checkout <tagname> # tagname seen in the previous output.
```

> How can I choose to save my own changes (such as modifications to .htaccess) rather than revert back whenever I update?

One way would be to make all your modifications in a separate branch and merge those changes after you have checked out a release tag.

> What's the best way to add my modules and themes into my local git repo, and still retain the ability to update core whenever there's a new core release? Do I need to create a branch?

You should use `git submodule` for this. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254633/how-do-you-combine-two-git-repos/2254679#2254679)

Comment: Thanks. So I have to switch back to master before I pull the latest changes? Is that always a rule?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, [drupal.org has a very nice guide](https://drupal.org/node/803746) which does not recommend submodules to keep up to date with core. You just dedicate a branch for this, and a remote pointing to git.drupal.org.